# Always try to stop daemon on shutdown without a lock file in /var/lock/subsys/

Tags: rhel, init-script, sysvinit

Normally, if a lockfile doesn't exist in `/var/lock/subsys/`, rhel doesn't try to stop the daemon, even though a link exists: `/etc/rc0.d/K??svcname`. 
There're daemons that are not always started by initscript, for example, an installer starts a database server directly, it doesn't know anything about initscripts.

I still need a graceful shutdown of the database.

How to workaround it?

I'm thinking of a special service `fake-lock-files` that starts early in all runlevels and creates the missing lock files.